# axis2 wsdl2java - on karaf axiom requirement missing

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, apache-axis, apache-karaf

I got a wsdl file from which I generated the java sources using axis2 wsdljava.

After building as a bundle and deploying it on apache karaf I get this error

```
[...] missing requirement [...] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.axiom.om)
```

And I got this in my pom.xml as depencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also got org.apache.axiom.om in my MANIFEST.MF which looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1444907709881
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60
Built-By: muellermak
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Ax WebService calls
Bundle-SymbolicName: AxWebServiceCall
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: axWebServiceCall.axPaygateService;uses:="org.apache.came
 l,axWebServiceCall.axPaygateService.generated";version="1.0.0",axWebSer
 viceCall.axPaygateService.generated;uses:="org.apache.axis2.transport,o
 rg.apache.axiom.om,org.apache.axiom.soap,org.apache.axis2.context,org.a
 pache.axis2.client,org.apache.axis2.description,javax.xml.namespace,org
 .apache.axis2,org.apache.axis2.util,org.apache.axis2.client.async,javax
 .xml.stream,org.apache.axis2.databinding,org.apache.axis2.databinding.u
 tils,org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader,org.apache.axis2.databin
 ding.types,org.apache.axiom.util.stax,javax.activation,org.apache.axis2
 .engine,org.apache.axis2.addressing";version="1.0.0",com.foo.myservice;
 uses:="org.apache.axis2.transport,***org.apache.axiom.om***,org.apache.axiom.
 soap,org.apache.axis2.context,org.apache.axis2.client,org.apache.axis2.
 description,javax.xml.namespace,org.apache.axis2,org.apache.axis2.util,
 org.apache.axis2.client.async,javax.xml.stream,org.apache.axis2.databin
 ding,org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils,org.apache.axis2.databinding.ut
 ils.reader,org.apache.axis2.databinding.types,org.apache.axiom.util.sta
 x,javax.activation,org.apache.axis2.engine,org.apache.axis2.addressing,
 org.apache.axis2.wsdl";version="1.0.0"
Export-Service: javax.sql.DataSource;osgi.jndi.service.name="jdbc/mysqlD
 atasource"
Import-Package: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional,javax.activation;version="
 [1.1,2)",javax.sql,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.stream;version="[1.0,2
 )",***org.apache.axiom.om***,org.apache.axiom.soap,org.apache.axiom.util.stax
 ,org.apache.axis2,org.apache.axis2.addressing,org.apache.axis2.client,o
 rg.apache.axis2.client.async,org.apache.axis2.context,org.apache.axis2.
 databinding,org.apache.axis2.databinding.types,org.apache.axis2.databin
 ding.utils,org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader,org.apache.axis2.d
 escription,org.apache.axis2.engine,org.apache.axis2.transport,org.apach
 e.axis2.util,org.apache.axis2.wsdl,org.apache.camel;version="[2.15,3)",
 org.apache.camel.component.sql,org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0
 .0,2.0.0)"
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

It also works fine when I try it without deploying it on karaf.

Can anyone help me resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

The Axiom JARs are OSGi bundles. The error message you get simply indicates that you haven't deployed them into Karaf.

Comment: When I deploy the axiom-api.jar on karaf I still get the same error. I'm pretty sure it's because the axiom-api is missing the requirement 'org.apache.james.mime4j' which is no bundle

Comment: Just found out that it works with an older version of axiom-api. But then it is missing org.apache.axis2...(which I got in my maven dependencies)

Comment: MIME4J is a bundle too and I doubt that you get the exact same error if you deploy axiom-api. What is the missing requirement in this case?

Comment: When I deploy the 1.2.15 version of axiom it is 'org.apache.james.mime4j' and with version 1.2.10 there is nothing missing (but the generated code still doesn't work because then axis2 is missing)

Comment: As I said earlier, mime4j is a bundle, so you need to deploy that as well. Axiom 1.2.15 uses mime4j 0.7.2. For the rest it is difficult to say because your question doesn't have details about how you build your bundle.

Comment: After I deployed mime4j the next one is coming and then another one again and this goes on and on ... isn't there another solution rather than deploying thousands of bundles? I'm building it with maven using the maven-bundle-plugin and I got '<Import-Package>*</Import-Package>'

Comment: That goes way beyond your original question. You should probably create a new question and explain what you are trying to achieve, your requirements and constraints, etc.